# What is a good pattern for owner/child JSON data in ManyToMany relationships using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am new to Spring, and I am trying to learn it, alongside with Hibernate.

I have a situation where I have `Users` and `Tasks` as entities, and I have a ManyToMany relationship between them. I've been able to implement this in Spring using the following classes,

```
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private String name;

  @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String username;

  private String profile_url;
  private String email;

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
    name = "user_tasks",
    joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    }
  )
  private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and

```
public class Task {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private String title;
  private String description;

  private double storyPoints;

  @CreationTimestamp
  private Instant creationTimestamp;

  @UpdateTimestamp
  private Instant updateTimestamp;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tasks", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I have tried many things, but I can't seem to fathom how to approach inserting `users` into the `task` json in my `Controller`. When I `POST` to `/api/users/` I should be able to use this `JSON` format,

```
{
    "name": "Hardworking Employee",
    "username": "employee",
    "email": "employee@company.com",
    "profile_url": "https://profile.pic",
}
```

and this works perfectly. When I `POST` to `api/tasks/`, ideally I would like to send something along these lines

```
{
    "title": "Do this also",
    "description": "Let's try to do this now",
    "storyPoints": 1.25,
    "users": [
        "employee"
    ]
}
```

Where the `users` key maps to an Array of `usernames` or perhaps an array of `ids`. However, this won't register correctly Jackson most likely expects the array of `Users`, and there is no `User` constructor with only one `String`. But even if there was, there would be no way of finding the correct user since this constructor would have to be created at the `model` level.

In general, I would like to know what is a good pattern to approach this problem? Should I put extra logic on my controller? Can someone guide me on the path to righteousness.

Comment: Hello @kaiser , your questions have many aspects to answer , to start with I would suggest you to check out below link that would help you to find out good approach   https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. To be more concrete, I suppose the gist of my question is the interplay between JSON and Hibernate. I have already checked the baeldung site, but I am confused since I am trying to learn best practices in REST API implementation.